# PyMongo: substrings match independent of words order

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I need a string search using pymongo MongoDB which check for substrings matches in a key, independently of the words order and case.

Let's see an example.

In my collections there are documents like the followings:

```
{'_id':..., 'key': 'the foo'}
{'_id':..., 'key': 'the bar'}
{'_id':..., 'key': 'the baz'}
```

If I searched for `'key'`, `'Fo tHe'`, `'foo t'` or `'foo the'` in the `key`, I would like to get `{'_id':..., 'key': 'the foo'}`.

The best solution I found is using regex via pymongo in this way:

```
query = {'key': {'$regex' : my_string, '$options':'i'}}
mycollection.find(query)
```

But this solution does not cover completely my requirements. E.g., it does not return the doc if `my_string = 'foo the'` (inverted word order).

Is there an efficient way to perform that kind of text searches in pymongo (MongoDB)?

Answer (score 1):

Try a full-text index:

```
mycollection.create_index([("foo", "text")])
```

Do that once, and then:

```
for doc in mycollection.find(
    {"$text": {"$search": "foo the"}}
).sort({"score": {"$meta": "textScore"}}):
    print(doc)
```

See [MongoDB Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) and [sort by meta](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/meta/#sort).

Comment: If I'm not wrong, a `$text` index does not support partial match for substring...